# AWS IoT Timestream Role doesn't save messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

few weeks ago I have implemented an AWS IoT Rule which writes all received values into a timestream table.

```
SELECT uplink_message.decoded_payload.temperature AS temperature, FROM 'lorawan/+/uplink' WHERE end_device_ids.application_ids.application_id = 'XXX-XXX-XXX' and uplink_message.f_port = 85
```

95 percent of received values are written correctly in timestream table but sometimes it doesn't.

For debugging reasons I have implemented an second rule and store all values into a dynamodb. ALL (100%) of received messages are saved in DynamoDb. It doesn't concern unique devices, it is completly random.

Comment: I would suggest to check if the problem is not overwriting data. I had the same issue where around 15% of the data was "missing" and, in fact, the data was being overwritten because the dimensions + time were the same for those 15% of data.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I wasn't issue with the SQL Version. I switched to SQL Version 2015-10-08 changed the code like this 
SELECT cast(uplink_message.decoded_payload.temperature as double) AS temperature
Now everthing is fine!